# jQuery nestedSortable - protect two levels from changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery nested sortable to display a tree of items and I would like to disable first TWO levels from changes. 
Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YgF4k/18/

HTML:

```
<ul id='menusList'>
    <li class='sortable_false'>
        <div> <span class='menu_name'>
                <a href="edit_this_item">root1</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    <ol class='sortable'>
        <li class="sortable_false" id="menu_161">
            <div> <span class='menu_name'>
                    <a href="edit_this_item">Child 1</a>
                </span> 
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="sortable_false" id="menu_163">
            <div> <span class='menu_name'>
                    <a href="edit_this_item">Child 2</a>
                </span> 
            </div>
            <ol>
                <li class="sortable_true" id="menu_162">
                    <div> <span class='menu_name'>
                          <a href="edit_this_item">Grandchild 1</a>
                      </span>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="sortable_true" id="menu_158">
                    <div> <span class='menu_name'>
                            <a href="edit_this_item">Grandchild 2</a>
                        </span>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="sortable_true" id="menu_160">
                    <div> <span class='menu_name'>
                            <a href="edit_this_item">Grandchild 3</a>
                        </span>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="sortable_false" id="menu_159">
            <div> <span class='menu_name'>
                <a href="edit_this_item">Child 3</a>
            </span>

            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <li class="sortable_false" id="menu_2">
        <div> <span class='menu_name'>
            <a href="edit_this_item">root2</a>
            </span>

        </div>
    </li>

</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.sortable').nestedSortable({
    handle: 'div',
    items: 'li',
    toleranceElement: '> div',
    protectRoot: true,
    update: function (event, ui) {
        $.post("/sort", $(this).nestedSortable('serialize'));
    }
});
```

In more details what I am still missing is:

1. Moving Grandchildren into Children level and vice verse should not be allowed.
2. Reordering of Children should not be allowed.
3. Moving Grandchildren between root1 Children and root2 Children should be allowed (ideally).

I've played some time with *protectRoot* and *items* options of nestedSortable, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using newest version of jQuery.ui.nestedSortable (which currently is 2.0) solves problems with protectRoot.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set the items as `li.sortable_true`...

```
$('.sortable').nestedSortable({
    handle: 'div',
    items: 'li.sortable_true',
    toleranceElement: '> div',
    protectRoot: true,
    update: function (event, ui) {
        $.post("/sort", $(this).nestedSortable('serialize'));
    }
});
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f9LyM/1/

also check out the jQuery UI docs, this extension inherits it: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items

Comment: This only solves point 2. Still I am able to move Grandchild to Child level